# How to get row order info in multivalued section?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using `MultivaluedSection` with an option `.Reorder` to reorder my cells, for which I need to know the exact order.

I tried with `section.allRows`, `form.allRows`, `form.values()` but seems like they all do not keep the information about order, even though they return an `Array`.

Note: I was trying to catch this data in overridden:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: This is [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized that after overriding that method I was "killing" that update, of course.

Still, I don't know how to "catch" when a change happens.